# How to play sound remotely using Text to Speech converter in python

Tags: python

Text to speech convertor is working fine with local machine but sound is not coming with live server
I have used both library (pyttsx3 ,gtts) separately

Comment: What are the things you tried? Can you paste the code part of it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
## Code ##
now = datetime.now()
dt_string = now.strftime("%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M_%S")
#Using pyttsx3
def texttospeech():
test = request.form.get('data')
engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.setProperty('rate', 150) 
en_voice_id = "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.Alex"
engine.setProperty('voice', en_voice_id)
engine.say(test)
engine.runAndWait()


#Using gTTS
def texttospeechmp3():
mytext = request.form.get('data')
language = 'en'
myobj = gTTS(text=mytext, lang=language, slow=False)
filename = "../static/"+dt_string+"_welcome.mp3"    
myobj.save(filename)    
return filename

It works with mp3
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.